# How to create "string" alias that can be combined with normal bash command?

Tags: linux, bash

Suppose I already defined

```
alias scpatoz='scp -r abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@helloworld.com'
```

in my `~/.bash_profile`. But sometimes I want to copy the `a` directory inside abc@helloworld.com to my computer. Normally I would do:

```
scp -r abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@helloworld.com:/home/a .
```

This takes a long time to type.

How can define the alias (the above definition does not work) so that I can do something like

```
scpatoz:/home/a .
```

? And then when a want to copy other directories, then I can also do:

```
scpatoz:/home2/b .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a small function such as this:

```
scpatoz()
{
    if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
        scp -r abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@helloworld.com:$1 .
    elif [ $# -gt 1 ]; then
        scp -r abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@helloworld.com:$@
    else
        echo "Needs argument"
    fi
}
```

then you could run `scpatoz /home/a` or add another argument to specify target location

Answer (score 0):

Enter your alias `scpatoz` or `scpatoz:/home/a .`, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to expand it, before running the command.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your command into a script like :

Script Name (`al.sh`) :

```
#!/bin/bash
scp -r abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@helloworld.com:$1 .
```

And then create an alias like :

```
alias scp="sh al.sh"
chmod +x al.sh        # Give execute permission
```

You can run this alias like :

```
scp /home/a
```

This will create a command like below and run :

```
scp -r abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@helloworld.com:/home/a .
```

This way whatever value you give to scp command like in our above case `/home/a` it will substitute the value of `$1` and run the scp command.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a variable name like
atozhost='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@helloworld.com'

Now you might be happy with typing 
scp -r ${atozhost}:/home/a .

When you want it even shorter, make a function like @Lepr answered. Use the variable `atozhost` in the function. I wouldn't use a function but look in the command history and edit the command (using the arrow keys or `CONTROL-R` and start typing `rcp`).